# "К реализации" или "на реализацию"?

Tags: склонение, предлоги, словосочетания

> К реализации предлагается....

Или нет разницы?

Comment: И сходите всё-таки к доктору. Одно другому не мешает...

Comment: Пояснение к предыдущему комментарию: автор вопроса жаловался на то, что у него "что-то отказало в голове" (затем я это удалил).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C разными глаголами сочетаются разные предлоги; вероятно, здесь это связано с разными свойствами "направленности" предлогов и с различиями в степени реальности действия, выражаемого глаголом.

**К реализации** предлагается, готовится, намечается... 
(объект - проект или продукт - *мысленно*, в намерениях приближают **к** факту его реализации)

**На реализацию** выставляется, направляется, поступает... 
(с объектом реализации производят *реальное* действие, "обрекая" его **на** реализацию)